# Hide a column in shiny datatable but keep it searchable

Tags: r, shiny, datatables

The DT package in Shiny produces a table with a searchbar that searches over every column in the table. I have a column of metadata which I do not want to display in the table, but I still want the rows to come up if I search with the search bar.

For example, the app below contains a column titled `searchCol` . This column is just letters. I want to hide this column in the actual table, and I want to be able to search for the letter `b` , using the DT search bar, and have the second row show up.

Is there a way to hide the column but have it still work with the search bar?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
    DTOutput('tbl1'),
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$tbl1 <- DT::renderDT(server = TRUE, {
        datatable(
            cbind(data.frame(replicate(3,sample(0:1,26,rep=TRUE))), data.frame(searchCol = letters)),
            escape = FALSE,
            rownames = FALSE, 
            filter = list(position = "top", clear = FALSE, plain = TRUE),             
            selection = "single",
            options = list(
                autoWidth = TRUE,
                pageLength = 50,
                lengthMenu = c(50, 100, 1000), 
                dom = 'Blfrtip',             
                buttons = c('copy', 'excel')
            )
        )
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've adapted the answer from [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/30881/how-to-enable-search-for-hidden-column) to the format you need to use in `DT::datatable`. You can use `columnDefs` to define the render options for the different columns, `targets` defines which column you mean. Please note that the JS library `datatables` starts counting columns at 0.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput('tbl1'),
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tbl1 <- DT::renderDT(server = TRUE, {
    datatable(
      cbind(data.frame(replicate(3,sample(0:1,26,rep=TRUE))), data.frame(searchCol = letters)),
      escape = FALSE,
      rownames = FALSE, 
      filter = list(position = "top", clear = FALSE, plain = TRUE),             
      selection = "single",
      options = list(
        autoWidth = TRUE,
        pageLength = 50,
        lengthMenu = c(50, 100, 1000), 
        dom = 'Blfrtip',             
        buttons = c('copy', 'excel'),
        columnDefs = list(
          list(
            targets = 3,
            searchable = TRUE,
            visible = FALSE
          )
        )
      )
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```